# Using UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning Without Storyboard Segues

Tags: ios, swift, animation, segue

I have been attempting to create a custom transitioning segue and have been following the online tutorials to help me. I am creating my app programmatically without the Storyboard.

I have a collection view cell that when tapped I would like to have a custom animated transition. All of the current tutorials use Storyboard segues. Most of the tutorials will create custom segues on the storyboard and then use some variation of the following function to call their custom segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
    let cell = sender as! PictureCell
    sourceCell = cell
    vc.picture = cell.picture.image

}
```

Because I am not using storyboards I figure I will have to call my animated transition in the didselectitem function:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}
```

I have all of the custom protocols and have set my UINaviationDelegate to include the custom animated transition:

```
extension FeedViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

    return PopInAndOutAnimator(operation: operation)
}
}

extension FeedViewController: CollectionPushAndPoppable {

var collectionView: UICollectionView? {
    return ideasCollectionView
}
}
```

Here is an example of a tutorial that I have followed: http://www.stefanovettor.com/2015/12/25/uicollectionview-custom-transition-pop-in-and-out/

How do I call my custom segue without the storyboard?

I would really appreciate the help. I have been trying to figure this issue out for the past week.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know one has to build the segue in storyboard and also you can provide the identifier to them which you can use to differentiate between segues. But I prefer to use a UINavigationController instead of Segue handling it's too convenient to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out Segues are only available if you use storyboards, so the prepare for segue will not work with xibs

You have created and set the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and now just want to start the animation to the other view controller.

Therefore you just need to call push on your navigation view controller:

```
let vc = DetailViewController(nibName: "DetailViewController", bundle: nil)
self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

This code creates and presents an instance of `DetailViewController` (rename to the correct name you use). If you set the delegate for the navigation view controller correctly, your custom animation will be applied.

Comment: Hi @nef10 I've attempted this and I keep getting the following error:  reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle. Is there something further I have to do? Do I have to create a nib file or change some sort of setting?

Comment: How have you defined your DetailViewController (ow however you named it). If you have a xib (=nib) for it the code should work. If the layout is only done in the code you need to use the normal init method.

Comment: Where and how do you set the delegate if you're not using the prepareForSegue method?